# In a chair at a club, what does it mean if somebody "wheels up their chair"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

From a short story by Algernon Blackwood, titled *If the Cap Fits* ([public domain PDF](http://algernonblackwood.org/Z-files/If_the_Cap_Fits.pdf)),

> Field-Martin, the naturalist, sat in his corner armchair at the Club [...]
>
> [...]. Field-Martin wheeled up his chair
> with vigorous strokes of his heels and joined the
> group [...]

The description is from the early decades of the 20th century. Does it mean to raise/erect the chair, as opposed to reclining? I assume there were chairs operated by heels?

Comment: Cite your sources please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items of furniture, including heavy padded armchairs and sofas, often have what are called 'castors'. One person could wheel or roll such a chair to move it, e.g. when cleaning, making the room tidy, or to re-position it. They help avoid damage to carpets or floors. It would be possible to move a chair while sitting, as described. The text is from the short story "If the Cap Fits" by Algernon Blackwood.

[image: a picture of an armchair with castors]

Comment: During World War 2, drunken Royal Air Force officers organised games in which seated officers were propelled, by several men, at each other at high speed in armchairs like these.

Answer (score 1):

It means he moved his chair along the ground towards the group; he must be in a wheelchair or another kind of chair that has wheels. Hence he was able to "wheel" it up to join the group. He was moving the chair using the heels of his feet as a source of propulsion.

Comment: Hmm there is nothing indicating that it was a wheelchair. It does read "armchair" a few sentences before this one. I have no idea if such a chair could have had - back then, and at clubs - wheels?

Comment: @JohnV "Wheel" in this context could also mean "turn quickly to face someone" in this case the group. Like if he "wheeled" the chair around.

But "wheeled up" and the description of him using his heels just sounds like he is on a chair with wheels.

To be clear it doesn't have to specifically be a wheelchair, and although armchair would be an odd synonym to use, plenty of wheeled chairs have arm rests and could colloquially be called "armchairs"

Comment: "moved his chair", +1. That's all we know. *wheel*  
>noun, 6 b : a directing or controlling force  
>verb, 4 : to travel on *or as if* on wheels or in a wheeled vehicle – [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wheel). But wheels are unlikely, especially with *up*. With wheels, you wheel a chair *over* (not up). If you *wheel it up with your heels* it makes that horrible noise and scratches the floor.